# Method not found even it exist in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

[image: Sample Request]I am using MVC Web API. I am facing one weird issue from past day. I have declared multiple method in constructor and try to called it. But every time it returns line "Method Not Found Exception". But I have declared method in controller and added in  config also. My code for controller is :

```
public class GlobalController : BaseApiController
{
    public GlobalController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Test")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(string id = "")
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CacheUser))]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/Global/Login")]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            CacheUser loginUser = CacheLib.Login(model);

            return Ok(loginUser);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw StaticLib.InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to call first method(i.e. Test). But whenever I try to call Login it returns method not found.

WebApiConfig contains :

```
// Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Global_DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/Global/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Global", action = "Test" }
        );
```

Any idea?

Stack trace is  :

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Method not
>   found: 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException
>   HSSystem.Libraries.API.StaticLib.InternalServerError(System.Exception)'.","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","StackTrace":"

Comment: I had tried with route attribute but issue was not resolved so I have just removed.

Comment: Show the actual, entire "method not found exception".

Comment: Also show web api config. Is attribute routing enabled?

Comment: I have added Stack trace. please look at that.

Comment: I can't see any issue in this action. If you send a post request with LoginModel values, it should work. Can you update the question with how you send post request.

Comment: @Sampath, I have added sample request.

Comment: So where does `HSSystem.Libraries.API.StaticLib.InternalServerError` come from? Are you sure the version of the library that you're building against is the same as the version present at deployment time?

Comment: Yes, All versions are same.

Comment: Why -1? I have added description.

Comment: Can you update Action with [FromBody] attribute and test. public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel model)

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: _"Why -1? I have added description"_ - it's still an incomplete question. Start by explaining what you have tried to resolve this error. A MissingMethodException usually means that you compile against a certain assembly containing a certain method, but that at runtime another assembly is loaded which lacks that method.

Comment: @CodeCaster - It seems like a best effort though. The error does look like it comes from the ASP.NET routing, at first sight.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar - your best bet here is to set up a small testproject and add only the necessary components. First get an empty Login() working, then add CacheLib. Because it looks like your issue comes from Some API version mismatch. And diagnostics could suffer from middleware.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I have tried with different methods and it's working. I have declare test method, it's working. Also I have added new method with post and just single string parameter it's working. But with Model it's not working.

Comment: And with a  `throw StaticLib.InternalServerError(ex);` ? I agree with @CodeCaster on the root cause.

Comment: I have checked routing also. Still issue is same.

Comment: So, is it the Model or the InternalServerError() ? Only you can eliminate one.

Comment: Actually, With model Post method is not working. Why I don't know.

Comment: When you've got a method that errors with Model but  without InternalServerError you should get a very different stacktrace. Post that method and the stack trace (just the first 5 lines is enough).

Comment: @HenkHolterman. Okay thanks. But can you please tell me what is the issue with my code? Because I am not able to make post request with LoginModel, but If  I am replace that with string username and string password it works.

Comment: I still see the same stack trace... and that doesn't match your description. Post the working method and the one that doesn't, exactly. And the exact error that it creates.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the missing method is, according to the exception:

```
System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException HSSystem.Libraries.API.StaticLib.InternalServerError(System.Exception)
```

This means that your controller compiles just fine against your `HSSystem.Libraries.API.StaticLib`, but that at runtime another assembly is loaded. So your `GlobalController.Login()` method is routed to and called, but when JITting its code (and finding the methods of other classes that are called within there), the exception is thrown because this specific version of the method `StaticLib.InternalServerError()` can't be found. Perhaps you changed the return type of that method, or added an optional parameter. This breaks the ABI.

Loading the wrong assembly can have many causes. Perhaps you reference another project which has a reference to an older or newer version of that assembly, which doesn't have that exact method, and *that* version gets copied on build. Or you have some kind of plugin system. Or, or, or.

Make sure you compile against the same version that's deployed at runtime.

Comment: I have checked all versions. It's same.

Comment: So again, check which version of `HSSystem.Libraries.API` is in your site's bin folder. Decompile it, or open it in the assembly explorer, to see whether that method is present.

Comment: Okay. Let me check one more time.

Comment: I have checked. It's contains method and I have checked version also. It's latest.

Comment: What do you mean by "it". The assembly in your bin folder?

Comment: Yes. I have checked that assembly and method also.